# What is the glVertexAttribPointer "stride" argument?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

just started learning openGL and, as usual, trying to understand what every bit of code i write does and why it is there, but i could not understand the **stride** argument is. 
according to the documentation it means (crude copy and paste ahead)

> Specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex
> attributes. If stride is 0, the generic vertex attributes are
> understood to be tightly packed in the array. The initial value is 0.

ok, the last part i can understand. when i did the array<sub>1</sub> like this (position tightly packed in the array)

```
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
      //x,     y,     z
        0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  // middle top
       -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f   // bottom right
    };
```

and **stride** has 0, it works :)

```
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

but if i add more attributes to it<sub>1</sub>

```
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
      //x,     y,     z,     r,     g,     b
        0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  // middle top
       -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f   // bottom right
    };
```

now **stride** is the size of each vertex, **WHY?**

`glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6*sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)0);`

if i try to use logic and put stride as 3, because it is the distance between one position and the next position on it<sub>1</sub> and it just does this for some reason
[(here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvmWr.png)

Comment: It is "the **byte offset** between consecutive generic vertex attributes. Each of your attributes has 6 components (x, y, z, r, g, b). Each component has 4 bytes (`sizeof(float)`). So the "stride" is `6*sizeof(GLfloat)`.

Comment: If "stride" is  set 0, the stride is automatically calculated form the "size" and the "type"

Comment: I tried to fix some of the formatting, but I didnt understand what that `<sub>` is supposed to be for

Comment: thanks for the formatting help, i am not very used to asking questions in this website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the **byte offset** between consecutive general vertex attributes. In your second example, each of your attribute tuples has 6 components (x, y, z, r, g, b) and each component has 4 bytes (`sizeof(float)`). The correct "stride" is therefore `6*sizeof(GLfloat)`.
If "stride" is set to 0, the distance is automatically calculated from "size" and "type" arguments, assuming that you have only one attribute in a consecutive array. In your first case the "size" is 3 and the "type" is `GL_FLOAT`, so the automatically calculated "stride" is `3*sizeof(GLfloat)`.

Comment: wow, this is making me question my knowledge of the english language but
can you explain it more simply? i couldn't understand it in the last 10 minutes

Comment: `If (strid == 0) { stride = sizeof(type) * size; }`. An element of type `float` has 4 bytes. So 6 "floats" have 6 * 4 bytes (`6 * sizeof(flaot))`.

Comment: i think i get it, the "stride" is the distance between each vertex to each other and the "pointer" is the distance between the start of the vertex to the attribute, right?

Comment: @octopus yes, *"the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes"*